# Dropdown only works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to hack in a drop down menu to an element in an ecommerce site where the show/hide couldn't be done with css due to html structure.

I came up with this code but it only works in chrome.  In IE & Firefox the dropdown instantly dissapears when the cursor leaves the blue and goes over the red.  Why is this and how should I fix it?

```js
$("#button").hover(
  function() {
    $("#mainmenu").show();
  },
  function() {
    if (!$("#mainmenu").is(":hover")) {
      $("#mainmenu").hide();
    }
  }
);

$("#mainmenu").hover(
  function() {
    
  },
  function() {
      $("#mainmenu").hide();

  }
);
```

```css
#button{
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#mainmenu{
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="mainmenu"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$("#mainmenu").show();` inside the first callback function of the `$("#mainmenu").hover()`:

```js
$("#button").hover(
  function() {
    $("#mainmenu").show();
  },
  function() {
    if (!$("#mainmenu").is(":hover")) {
      $("#mainmenu").hide();
    }
  }
);

$("#mainmenu").hover(
  function() {
    $("#mainmenu").show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#mainmenu").hide();

  }
);
```

```css
#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#mainmenu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="mainmenu"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  I will mark soon as time limit allows.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this bit from `$("#button").hover()`:

```
  function() {
    if (!$("#mainmenu").is(":hover")) {
      $("#mainmenu").hide();
    }
```

This works for me in IE as you intended it to:

```js
$("#button").hover(
  function() {
    $("#mainmenu").show();
  }  
);

$("#mainmenu").hover(
  function() {
    
  },
  function() {
      $("#mainmenu").hide();

  }
);
```

```css
#button{
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#mainmenu{
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button"></div>
<div id="mainmenu"></div>
```

Comment: menu stays open if you dont go into red, it needs to close when mouse goes off it

Comment: Ah I didn't test thoroughly enough; @lonut's solution does the trick.